# looking for IDE RoR and Yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a project In RoR with Yaml, but I use TextMate, but I don´t like it.

What is the best IDE to use Yaml with Ruby on rails.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question will best closed. Since it dosent belong here. But check rubymine for paid ide and aptana if you want a free one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite happy with [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and its [Ruby and Rails support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ruby_rails.html).

For more text-editory things, [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is a great cross-platform choice.

Emacs is my third-runner-up, mostly because I haven't used it enough over the last 5-10 years to be as fluid with it as I once was, but it's the best text editor ever. <sub>Let the Emacs/Vi war begin!</sub>

Comment: And if you don't want to buy IntelliJ just for Ruby development, JetBrains, the creators of IntelliJ, also sell RubyMine, which is for Ruby and Ruby on Rails specifically.